# Html.PasswordFor is not populated?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I spend a lot of my time, trying to understand why in a razor expression of

```
@HTML.PasswordFor( m => m.Password)
```

I can't set the value from the model the only solution that I found it's injecting the value by html properties like this

```
@HTML.PasswordFor( m => m.Password, new { value = Model.Password })
```

Am I doing something wrong?? is the correct helper?? this is the field model configuration

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "La contraseña es obligatoria.")]
[StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "El {0} debe tener al menos {2} caracteres de longitud.", MinimumLength = 6)]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Display(Name = "Contraseña")]
public string Password { get; set; }
```

It's the only solution?

Comment: This behavior is by design.  Do not send passwords downstream in HTTP requests

Comment: That makes no sense considering the cases where you just received the passwords over the same wire. Anybody wanting to intercept the password already has it, so not allowing it to be sent back across the wire has no benefit and inconveniences users. Poor design choice imho.

Comment: Providing your implementing SSL (which you should be) the wire is secure. **The browser on the other hand is not secure**. So it makes perfect sense not to put passwords into markup. No one should know your password, not even the admin (they should be hashed immediately). You'd imagine all the recent password breaches would tell people that not taking this kind of thing seriously is a bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a security feature. To make this work implies that a) you are able to access the users password in plain text and b) are transmitting it over the wire to their browser.

Neither of which are safe and shouldn't be encouraged.

As such, this is a feature of Razor, rather than an issue.

Comment: Whilst it shouldn't be encouraged there are legitimate reasons to use the password input type such as masking keys that the user needs to access. In my case, I use the password input type to hide the key and then let the user toggle it on/off. To get around this issue I create a new HTML attribute called `value` and set the value that way.